# Symmetry in a sequence of linear orders

Tags: permutations, order-theory, symmetry

I would like to know if the following conjecture is correct and/or already known. Do you have any ideas for a demonstration or counter-example?
Thank you.

Let $X$ be a finite set and $(P_i)_{i\in N}$ a finite sequence of linear orders of $X$ such that 
$$\forall x,y\in X,\quad
|\{i\in N \mid xP_iy\}|=|\{i\in N \mid yP_ix\}|.$$
For each linear order $P$, we define $\bar{P}$ as follows: $\ a\bar{P}b$  if and only if $bPa.$

Conjecture: There exists a partition $\{N_0,N_1\}$ of $N$ and a bijection $b:N_0\rightarrow N_1$ sur that for each $i\in N_0$, $P_{b(i)}=\bar{P_i}$.

Comment: Almost any example is a counterexample ... what have you looked at?

Comment: $|N|$ cannot be odd. Let denote by $\pi_{xy}$ the cardinal of $i\in N$ such that $xP_iy$. Since every $i\in N$ either "prefers" $x$ to $y$ or $y$ to $x$,  we have  $\pi_{xy}+\pi_{yx}=|N|$ and by hypothesis, $\pi_{xy}=\pi_{yx}$. It follows that $N$ is even.

Comment: No, $(P_i)_{i\in N}$ is a finite sequence of linear orders satisfying the condition specified in my first message. Another way of putting this is as follows: if $(P_i)_{i\in N}$ is such that ∀,∈,|{∈∣}|=|{∈∣}|, then there exists a permutation $b$ of $N$ such that $P_{b(i)}=\bar{P_i}$

Answer (score 0):

I just found a counterexample:
$P_1=(a,b,c,d)$, $P_2=(c,b,a,d)$, $P_3=(d,c,a,b)$, $P_4=(d,b,a,c)$.